# Correct way to use PyArray_SimpleNewFromData?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, python-extensions

I am trying to create a numpy array in a python extension.
The call of PyArray_SimpleNewFromData gives me a segfault.
I am trying to fix it for hours, and now I am the point where I have no more idea on how that could occur. Here is a self-containing example to reproduce it:

$ cat test.c

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"

 void main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char* data;
    npy_intp dims[2];
    data = malloc(20);
    if(NULL == data)
        exit(-1);
    strncpy(data,"helloworld",10);
    dims[0] = 5;
    dims[1] = 2;
    PyObject* result = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dims, NPY_BYTE, data);
}
```

$ gcc $(python3-config --includes) -g -o test test.c $(python3-config --libs)

$ echo "run;bt" | gdb test

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from test...done.
(gdb) Starting program: /home/mag/project/mouse/test ;bt
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554dc6 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffddc8) at test.c:16
16      PyObject* result = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dims, NPY_BYTE, data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably numpy was not initialized. Adding the following lines to the beginning of main() helped:

```
 Py_Initialize();
 import_array();
```